# Qt/c++: How to set platform independent application icon?

Tags: c++, qt

I am developing my Qt (c++) application on MacBook. However, the application might run in both Windows and Mac Systems.

Is there is a way to set platform independent application icon ?!

Answer (score 1):

Setting application icons is already independent, Windows and OS X require different icon formats: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/appicon.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my question I meant that whenever the app starts, whether on Windows or Mac, it should load the app icon regardless of the OS. I think I need to check the OS first and upon that the system should assign the corresponding icon format, right ?

Comment: If you follow the instructions in that link it'll explain the differences, how you set the application icon differs per platform so you don't need to do any OS checks.

Answer (score 0):

> the application might run in both Windows and Mac Systems

Right, but not the same executable (binary), you'll compile two versions, one for Windows and one for Mac. Executable icon could be displayed by the OS (when aplication icon is shown on desktop, task bar...) before the application is actually started. So this icon cannot be set programmatically, it must be set at compilation time. And, you must refer to [this post](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/appicon.html) to know how to set the application icon for binaries on each different platform.